# order of evaluation for multiple increment operator on pointer

Tags: c, pointers, operators, increment

Having trouble understanding, How following statement would be evaluated :

```
++*++ptr and *ptr++++
```

As per my understanding first would give me lValue required because after * is applied it would give value which cannot be used for ++ operator. But, the result is opposite. Please explain.

Second statement gives me error : batch3.c:6:21: error: lvalue required as increment operand
  printf("%d", *ptr++++);

Answer (score 2):

First, some [standardese](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators**
> **Constraints**
> 1 The operand of the postfix increment or decrement operator shall have atomic, qualified,
> or unqualified real or pointer type, **and shall be a modifiable lvalue**.
>
> **Semantics**
> 2 The result of the postfix `++` operator is the value of the operand. As a side effect, the
> value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is
> added to it). **See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for
> information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on
> pointers.** The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of
> updating the stored value of the operand. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced
> function call, the operation of postfix `++` is a single evaluation. Postfix `++` on an object
> with atomic type is a read-modify-write operation with `memory_order_seq_cst`
> memory order semantics.<sup>98)</sup>
> ...
> **6.5.16 Assignment operators**
> ...
> 3 An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An
> assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,<sup>111)</sup> **but is not
> an lvalue**. The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have
> after lvalue conversion. The side effect of updating the stored value of the left operand is
> sequenced after the value computations of the left and right operands. The evaluations of
> the operands are unsequenced.

Emphasis mine.

The upshot of that wall of text is that the results of the expressions `ptr++` and `++ptr` are not lvalues.  However, both expressions result in pointer values, so they may be the operands of the unary `*` operator, and the results of `*ptr++` and `*++ptr` *may* be lvalues.

This is why `++*++ptr` works; you're incrementing the result of `*++ptr`, which may be an lvalue.  However, `*ptr++++` is parsed as `*(((ptr)++)++)` (postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`); the result of `ptr++` is the operand to the second `++`, but since the result of `ptr++` is not an lvalue, the compiler complains.  If you had written it as `(*ptr++)++`, then the expression would be valid.

In short:

```
++*++ptr     - valid, equivalent to ++(*ptr++)
*++++ptr     - invalid, equivalent to *(++(++ptr)), result of ++ptr is not an lvalue
++++*ptr     - invalid, equivalent to ++(++(*ptr)), result of ++*ptr is not an lvalue
*ptr++++     - invalid, equivalent to *((ptr++)++), result pf ptr++ is not an lvalue
(*ptr)++++   - invalid, equivalent to ((*ptr)++)++, result of (*ptr)++ is not an lvalue
(*ptr++)++   - valid
```

Comment: Isn't the result of unary `*` _always_ an lvalue?

Answer (score 1):

`++` operator has higher precedence over `*`

So the pointer will be incremented first and then dereferenced.

```
*p++
```

First

```
p++
```

Then `*p++`

For `++` there has to be a value which needs to be incremented. But the below expression doesn't provide the lvalue for the `++` . `p++` is not a modifiable lvalue.

```
*ptr++++;
```

Comment: Gopi I understand that, I need explanation why second statement gives me 

error: lvalue required as increment operand
  printf("%d", *ptr++++);

Answer (score 1):

Considering that these two expressions are separate (note that `and` is defined `<iso646.h>`) here what happens:

First one `++*++ptr` is equivalent to `++(*(++ptr))`, as both prefix `++` and unary `*` have the same [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and assiociativity is from right to left for both of them. See following [example](http://ideone.com/Thtqfe) as an illustration:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {1, 2};
    int *ptr = a;

    ++(*(++ptr));

    printf("%d\n", a[0]);
    printf("%d\n", a[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1
3
```

The latter expression is not compilable, as `ptr++` subexpression is not a *modifiable lvalue*. Note that postix `++` has higher precedence, that `*` (indirection operator) and its associativity is from left to right.

Comment: Accepted but would *(++ptr) give modifiable lvalue ? First statement also should give me error then right ?

Comment: @Sagrian: In fact `*(++ptr)` is such lvalue, just the same as `*ptr` would be. Added example to illustrate how it works.